# Play framework showing error as flows while running my newly created application

Tags: playframework

Play framework showing error as flows while running my newly created application. Here is the my shell steps and error stack.

```
C:\play-2.0>play new mysample
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/

play! 2.0, http://www.playframework.org

The new application will be created in C:\play-2.0\mysample

What is the application name?
> mysample

Which template do you want to use for this new application?

  1 - Create a simple Scala application
  2 - Create a simple Java application
  3 - Create an empty project

> 2

OK, application mysample is created.

Have fun!


C:\play-2.0>cd mysample

C:\play-2.0\mysample>play
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
error: error while loading AnnotatedElement, class file 'C:\Program Files\Java\j
re1.8.0_31\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 2682)
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 2.4.3 version of Play. Play 2.0 may use old Scala version, like 2.9.x.  That Scala version produce this error with JDK 8.

You need to have Scala 2.10.3+ to run on JDK 8.